# OpenPoseで取得した全てのjsonファイルから座標をcsvとして保存

Tags: python

動画からOpenposeで取得した全てのjsonファイルからx、yの座標をcsvとして保存する方法はありますか。今はひとつ一つのファイルから座標を抽出していますけど、コードは下のような感じです。

```
def json_data (path):
  with open(path) as f:
      data = json.load(f)
      data = np.array(data['people'][0]['pose_keypoints_2d']).reshape(-1,3)
      df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['X','Y','P']).drop("P", axis=1)
  
  return df[df['X'] != 0.000]
```

Comment: ループ処理すれば良いかと思います。「取得した全てのjsonファイル」は1つのフォルダに保存されているのでしょうか？具体的な課題は、”複数ファイルの扱い”でしょうか？”csvとして保存”でしょうか？

Comment: こんな記事が参考になるかも。[OpenPoseのJSON形式をCSVに変換する](https://kimbio.info/openpose%E3%81%AEjson%E5%BD%A2%E5%BC%8F%E3%82%92csv%E3%81%AB%E5%A4%89%E6%8F%9B%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B/)

Comment: jsonファイルは１つのフォルダに保存されています。＠merino

Comment: ありがとうございます。参考になります。@kunif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> data = np.array(data['people'][0]['pose_keypoints_2d']).reshape(-1,3)
> df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['X','Y','P']).drop("P", axis=1)

を

```
data = data['people'][0]['pose_keypoints_2d']
del data[2::3]
```

にするとx, y座標だけの配列になります。
dataを返り値に設定し、全てのファイルでループし1つの配列にappendしていくといいと思います。

ループをする際は、natsortというライブラリを用いるといいと思います。
以下のコードの `'path/to/jsons'` にjsonが格納されているディレクトリを指定すると、
取得したjsonが順番に得られます。

```
from natsort import natsorted
natsorted(os.listdir('path/to/jsons'))
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON ファイル(`*.json`)が `data` ディレクトリ以下にあるとして、単一のファイル(`coordinates.csv`)にキーポイントの `X`, `Y` 座標を出力します。

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from glob import glob

def json_data(path):
  arr = np.reshape(pd.read_json(path)['people'][0]['pose_keypoints_2d'], (-1, 3))[:,:2]
  return arr[arr[:,0]!=0.0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
  coordinates = np.concatenate([json_data(f) for f in glob('./data/*.json')])
  np.savetxt('coordinates.csv', coordinates, delimiter=',', fmt='%f', header='X,Y', comments='')
```